# jQuery menu not collapsing in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I need some help with this.  Basically I’ve created a menu bar using a combination of JQuery and css and it's not collapsing or hiding the way it should in Safari (I'm using 6.1.6).

I'll start with the code first

**CSS Code**

```
#menuHolder
{
    width:200px;
    height:30px;
    background:#CCC;
    position:fixed;
    top:10px;
    border: thin ridge #333;
}

#menuItem1
{

    margin:0.15em;
    display:table;
    float:left;
    width:150px;
    height:25px;
    background:#666;

}



#menuDiv
{
    background-color:#FFF;
    height:100px;
    width:150px;

    opacity:1;
    visibility:hidden;



    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;

    position:absolute;
    top:34px;
    margin-left:.1em;   
}




#menuItem1:hover
{   
    background:#06F;

}


#menuItem1:hover #menuDiv
{
    opacity:1;
    visibility:visible;

    background-color:#F00;


    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;        
}

#menuContents
{
    font-size:10px;


}


.ui-menu 
{
   width: 150px;     
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>


<div id="menuHolder">

<div id="menuItem1">
    Menu 1    
    <div id="menuDiv">

        <ul id="menuContents">

               <li>Main Menu 1
                    <ul>
                        <li>Mid Menu 1
                            <ul>

                                <li>Sub Menu 1.1</li>


                                <li>Sub Menu 1.2</li>

                            </ul>
                        </li>
                   </ul>
               </li>
         </ul>

    </div>

</div>

</div>

</body>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
    $( "#menuContents" ).menu();
});
```

**The Issue**

As you can see from the code, when the mouse pointer goes to the menuItem1 div it will highlight the div and unhide the menuDiv that holds the jQuery menuContents.  This works all fine and well, until you click on any of the submenu items.

In other browsers (Opera, Mozilla, Chrome) when you click the submenus, the menus collapse normally, menuDiv fades away, and menuItem1 unhighlights.  In Safari, the mid and submenus fade away, but menuDiv never fades away, and menuItem1 remains highlighted as if there is still a mouse pointer triggering the css.

I am unsure if this is a CSS issue, a jQuery issue, or a browser version issue. Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue was solved when I upgraded to Yosemite which means it was a Safari issue after all. All the menus collapse normally with no issues. –